# What is a common name for these automorphic objects?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

I am looking for a name which includes these objects:
1. automorphic forms, cusp forms and non-cusp forms
2. Rankin-Selberg convolution between automorphic forms (which is conjectured to be automorphic forms but not yet proved for most cases)
3. Langlands functorial liftings (which is conjectured to be automorphic forms but not yet proved for most cases)

I can't call them automorphic forms because 2 and 3 are not.
I can't call them L-functions because 1 can produce more than standard L-function.

Comment: This paper might be of interest to you: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3067.pdf

Comment: I suggest the name "conjectural functorial forms".

Comment: Are you talking about (adelic potentially automorphic) forms or $L$-functions?  (Automorphic forms includes cusp forms and non-cusp forms, but there are different paradigms: $L^2$, smooth, ...)  Anyway, I suggest you define a class of objects $\mathcal A$ to be whatever you precisely mean.